# How can I use the results of a DIR Query as VAR's

Tags: batch-file

I am working on a Batch file and have made it pretty easy to use, but I would like it "Fool Proof" or as close as I can get. 
What I am currently doing it displaying a list of folders and asking the user to type out the name of the folder from the list they are using. What I would like is if they could just type 1 for the first result, 2 for the second and so on.

Current lines in question

```
DIR /b "c:\ProgramData\Nuance\%var1%\Users\" | findstr /v "(DGN_RENAMED)" 
SET/p var2="Please type out the Provider voice file name from the list above."%
```

Which will display folder names like below

Cameron

JeffG

DR. Lemper

Snyder

Then the user would have to type in JeffG, which leaves room for error, It wont break anything but will waste a few seconds.

What I would like is to display the folders listed in "c:\ProgramData\Nuance\%var1%\Users\" numbered and set them as variables like Below and have ot to where they only need to type in the number associated to the folder name

1.Cameron

2.JeffG

3.Dr.Lemper

4.Snyder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set index=1
for /f %%i in ('dir /b /ad "c:\ProgramData\Nuance\%var1%\Users\" ^| findstr /v "(DGN_RENAMED)"') do (
    set !index!=%%i
    echo !index!.%%i
    set /a index=!index!+1
)
set /p var2="Please type out the Provider voice file name from the list above: "
echo The answer is %var2%, corresponding folder name is "!%var2%!"
```

Now the output looks like the one showed below and a user only needs to type in the appropriate number. Folder names are located in the corresponding variables (`1`,`2`,`3`, etc.). To access them use exclamation marks `!` instead `%` (for instance, `!1!`) because otherwise cmd.exe tries to interpret them as argument variables.

`1.cameron
 2.dr.lemper
 3.jeffg
 4.snyder
 Please type out the Provider voice file name from the list above: 2
 The answer is 2 which is folder "dr.lemper"`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /a count=0

for /f "tokens=*" %%d in ('dir /b "C:\Users\*"') do (
    set /a count+=1
    @echo !count!. %%d 
)
pause
```